# Sprite lagging in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Here is some pygame code it works fine except to move the sprite i have to repeatedly tap the arrow keys, is there a way to make the sprite move by holding down the arrow keys? Below is my code:

```
while True: #main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                LionCubX+= 10
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                LionCubX-= 10
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                LionCubY-= 10
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                LionCubY+= 10
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(GREEN)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(LionCubImg,(LionCubX,LionCubY))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I don't know much about pygame, but the problem is probably that you use `KEYUP`, which implies you must release the key in order to cause movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I can see here is that you check for events of type `KEYUP`. This means that your Code only gets executed when you release the key. So change

```
elif event.type == KEYUP:
```

to

```
elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
```

Another possibility would be that you didn't set key repeat:

```
pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 30)
```

Put this before your main game loop to activate key repeat. Also see [the docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're moving your sprite only if a key has been depressed and released `KEYUP`. You need to move the sprite in the key state `KEYDOWN`.

Change this:

```
elif event.type == KEYUP:
```

To:

```
elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
```